# Invalid Report File Path error - Crystal Reports w/ stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I have a VB.Net app that creates a crystal report using datasets from various datasources that go into separate subreports. The report displays fine until I try to use a stored procedure as a subreport's datasource, in which case I get the error "Invalid Report File Path".

This stored procedure needs to concatenate a number to the column name to avoid duplicating code.

I've set breakpoints right where the dataset gets populated, checked the dataset contents, and found that all the desired data is in the dataset but I'll get the error when I step through to the point where the report opens. When I execute the stored procedure in SQL Server the data returns with no problem. If I remove the subreport that uses the stored procedure, the report will generate fine. Wondering if the stored procedure needs to be coded differently...? or something else?

Here's the code for the stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[T_STORED_PROC]
(

@qmonth varchar(20),
@qyear varchar (4),
@qid varchar (10)
)
AS


DECLARE @i varchar(10)
DECLARE @sql varchar(1000)

SET @i = 1

WHILE (@i <=28)
BEGIN
 SET @sql ='SELECT t1.ID, t2.CatId, t2.CatName, t1.M_'+ @i +'_DATE As Mid_Date 
FROM Table1 As t1, Table2 As t2 WHERE t2.CatId = RTRIM(LEFT(t1.M_'+ @i +', 2)) 
AND t1.ID = '''+ @qid +''' AND t1.Yr = '+ @qyear +' AND t1.M_Month = '''+ @qmonth +''' 
ORDER BY t1.ID'

    EXEC (@sql)

END
```

and the relevant VB is here

```
Dim dsQRpt = New Data.DataSet
 Dim dsMS = New Data.DataSet
 Dim QPrpt = New ReportDocument

 Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
        cmd.Connection = MSCON
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.T_STORED_PROC"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@qmonth", OleDbType.VarChar, 20, ParameterDirection.Output).Value = cboMonth.SelectedValue
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@qyear", OleDbType.VarChar, 4, ParameterDirection.Output).Value = cboYear.SelectedValue
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@qid", OleDbType.VarChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Output).Value = txtPTSID.Text

        Dim DAms As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, MSCON)

        DAms.SelectCommand = cmd

        DAms.Fill(dsQRpt)

        QPrpt.Load(Server.MapPath("crReport.rpt"))
        QPrpt.SetDataSource(dsQRpt)
        crQtrProgress.ReportSource = QPrpt
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem. It looks like Crystal Reports wasn't recognizing the database fields that were stored in a SQL variable. I changed the stored procedure so that the query results populate a temp table I created and then I grab the database fields from that. Here's the working stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[T_STORED_PROC]
(

@qmonth varchar(20),
@qyear varchar (4),
@qid varchar (10)
)
AS

--Temp table
DECLARE @tmp table
(
ID nvarchar(10),
CategoryId int,
CategoryName nvarchar(50),
CatDate datetime
)

DECLARE @i varchar(10)
DECLARE @sql varchar(1000)

SET @i = 1

WHILE (@i <=28)
BEGIN
 SET @sql ='SELECT t1.ID, t2.CatId, t2.CatName, t1.M_'+ @i +'_DATE As Mid_Date 
FROM Table1 As t1, Table2 As t2 WHERE t2.CatId = RTRIM(LEFT(t1.M_'+ @i +', 2)) 
AND t1.ID = '''+ @qid +''' AND t1.Yr = '+ @qyear +' AND t1.M_Month = '''+ @qmonth +''' 
ORDER BY t1.ID'

--INSERT results into temp table
INSERT INTO @tmp

    EXEC (@sql)

END

--SELECT from temp table
SELECT ID As ID,
CategoryId AS CategoryId,
CategoryName AS CategoryName,
CatDate As CatDate
FROM @tmp
```